# How to access children of the firebase realtime db

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have used FirbaseRecyclerAdapter but i am getting trouble to finding the value of child  following is the code i have used

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listitems = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("content");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Listitem ,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Listitem, BlogViewHolder>(
                Listitem.class,R.layout.list_item,BlogViewHolder.class,databaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Listitem model, int position) {
                viewHolder.sethead(model.getHead());
                viewHolder.setdesc(model.getDesc());



            }

        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `-L7n...Udk3D` key under `duck`, which is most likely the reason that your `Listitem` model class can't look up the `head` and `description` properties. To fix it, get rid of the extra `-L7n...Udk3D` key.